# Draytek Vigor VPN hide-NAT

Tags: vpn, draytek

I've got an end-user trying to connect their branch office to my site, and they are using a Draytek Vigor 2862.

On our side, we expect the branch offices to hide-NAT their traffic before reaching us, so we don't have to manage swathes of RFC1918 address space.  Usually we do this behind the fixed IP of the branch office WAN connection.  The branches are never required to talk to each other.

```
branch-lan                     branch-wan                  hq-wan             hq-lan
192.168.a.0/24   --- NAT -->   77.x.x.x     --- VPN --->   213.y.y.y   --->   172.31.b.0/20
```

In the Cisco ASA world (where I am most comfortable), I would simply establish the tunnel with an access-list matching source=77.x.x.x and dest=172.31.b.b/20, and then deliberately *not* include that source/dest pair in a `nat 0` (or identity NAT) policy, and allow the default NAT from 0.0.0.0 to 77.x.x.x to take place, e.g.

```
object network BRANCH_LAN
  subnet 192.168.a.0 255.255.255.0
object network HQ_LAN
  host 172.31.b.0/20
object network ANY_IPV4
  subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0

access-list HQ_VPN extended permit ip interface OUTSIDE object HQ_LAN

nat (INSIDE,OUTSIDE) after-auto source dynamic BRANCH_LAN interface destination static ANY_IPV4 ANY_IPV4

crypto map CRYPTOMAP 10 match address HQ_VPN
crypto map CRYPTOMAP 10 set peer 213.y.y.y
...

tunnel-group 213.y.y.y
```

In the Draytek world, there seem to be a number of tick-box options for NAT, and none of them seem to do anything sane.  Specifically, under the **VPN and Remote Access >> LAN to LAN** profile options, **TCP/IP Network settings** section:

1. I can set Local Network/Mask and Remote Network/Mask
2. There is an dropdown field named *From first subnet to remote network, you have to do* with options *Route* or *NAT*
3. There is a tickbox field for *IPsec VPN with the Same Subnets*

Option #1 is presumably the tunnel encryption domain, we set Local and Remote to the `77.x.x.x` and `172.31.b.0/20` addresses, respectively.

Choosing option #3 alters hides option #2 and changes option #1 so that you can only enter a Remote Network IP/Mask.  You can then choose to translate local networks (via a dropdown containing *LAN1* to *LAN4*) to a given address.  Additionally, a *Virtual IP Mapping* button is enabled, which allows you to provide virtual IPs and real IPs.

Setting option #2 to *NAT* hides option #3.  It does not provide any additional field to determine *what* the source address is translated *to*.

The documentation for option #2 *helpfully* says:

> If the remote network only allows you to dial in with single IP, please choose **NAT**, otherwise choose **Route**.

Option #3 appears to provide a tighter control over IP address mapping but, in practice, this seems only to provide a one-to-one mapping within a same-sized subnet, e.g. 192.168.a.1 becomes 192.168.b.1, 192.168.a.2 becomes 192.168.b.2, etc.

Setting option #2 to *NAT* looks to be the closest to the typical hide-NAT, but it does not indicate *what* address is actually used in place of the LAN range.

In any case, I have found no combination of these options which allows both the tunnel to establish *and* traffic to flow from the branch to the HQ.  We've managed to get the tunnel to establish *without* traffic flow, but what use is that?!

There is a demo interface for the Draytek at http://eu.draytek.com:12862/, to illustrate the options above.

Now, before this becomes just a *rant* without a *question*, can anyone with any solid Draytek experience tell me...

- what end-users are source-translated as, when *From first subnet to remote network, you have to do* is set to *NAT*?
- whether the *Local Network IP/Mask* should refer to the local part of the encryption domain (i.e. 77.x.x.x), or if it should always refer to the local LAN (192.168.a.0/24)?
- what Draytek sends as the encryption domain, during the VPN handshake, when *NAT* is chosen?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is only only model can do this :

https://www.draytek.com/products/vigor2960/

And here you can read howto:
https://www.draytek.com/support/knowledge-base/4300

...It took me a long long time to figure this out .....

Comment: I've read that KB many times, but it doesn't really address the questions, specifically. Draytek documentation seem to think that "NAT" is just some simple tick-box that *applies* to a VPN, but it really is far more nuanced than that...